# Creating matrix shifted by one column every row

Tags: r

Is there an efficient way to shift a matrix by one column every row starting from the top or the bottom?

For example, consider the following matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15
```

If shifting from the bottom up, it should look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]   NA   NA    1    4    7   10   13
[2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   14   NA
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   NA   NA
```

If shifting from the top down, it should look like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   14   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    3    6    9   12   15
```

Here's how I might do it with a for loop, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way:

```
oldNumCols <- ncol(matrix.data)
newNumCols <- sum(dim(matrix.data))-1
shiftedData <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(matrix.data), ncol = newNumCols)
for(i in 1:nrow(matrix.data))
{
  #posToReplace <- newNumCols - oldNumCols + 1:oldNumCols - i + 1 # shifting from the bottom up
  posToReplace <- 1:oldNumCols + i - 1 # shifting from the top down
  shiftedData[i,] <- replace(shiftedData[i,], posToReplace, matrix.data[i,])
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking there should be a way to leverage `lower.tri()`, and/or `upper.tri()` and leveraging `diag = FALSE` - for example, look at the results of `matrix.data[lower.tri(matrix.data, diag = FALSE)] <- NA`

Comment: Try `indx <- seq(oldNumCols) +rep(seq(nrow(matrix.data))-1, each=oldNumCols);
 shiftedData[cbind(rep(1:nrow(matrix.data), each=oldNumCols), indx)] <- matrix.data` This is for the second one.  For the first replace the indx accordingly.

Comment: There was a typo `shiftedData[cbind(rep(1:nrow(matrix.data), each=oldNumCols), indx)] <- t(matrix.data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try some fancy matrix indexing to place the values. For example here's a function that can help

```
rowslide <- function(x, bottomup=FALSE) {
    m <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(x), ncol=ncol(x)+nrow(x)-1)
    a <- -1
    b <- nrow(x)
    if(bottomup) {
        a <- 1
        b <- -1
    }
    idx<-cbind(
        rep(1:nrow(x), each=ncol(x)),
        a*rep(1:nrow(x), each=ncol(x))+1:ncol(x)+b
    )
    m[idx]<-t(x)
    m
}
```

And we test it with

```
x<-matrix(1:15, nrow=3)

rowslide(x)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10   13   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   14   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA    3    6    9   12   15

rowslide(x, TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]   NA   NA    1    4    7   10   13
# [2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   14   NA
# [3,]    3    6    9   12   15   NA   NA
```

Comment: I didn't see that you added a solution before.  My page didn't update.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possibilities including speed test. The first one uses the "shift"-function from the "binhf"-library:

```
library(binhf)

M <- matrix(1:12,3,4)

system.time(
  for ( t in 1:100000 )
  {
    n <- nrow(M)
    m <- ncol(M)

    A <- cbind(M,matrix(NA,n,n-1))

    for (i in 1:n) { A[i,] <- shift(A[i,],i-1) }
  }
)
```

It is shorter, but slower:

```
       User      System verstrichen 
       9.64        0.00        9.73 
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    3    6    9   12
```

The "base R"-solution:

```
M <- matrix(1:12,3,4)

system.time(
  for ( t in 1:100000 )
  {
    n <- nrow(M)
    m <- ncol(M)

    k <- (0:(n-1))*(m+n)+1
    i <- outer(k,1:m,"+")-1

    a <- rep(NA,n*(m+n-1))
    a[i] <- M

    A <- matrix(a,n,m+n-1,byrow=TRUE)
  }
)
```

It is longer, but faster:

```
       User      System verstrichen 
       4.09        0.00        4.18 
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    3    6    9   12
```

This is the matrix I used for the test:

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

I repeated the test using a 15-by-20-matrix. Result for the "shift"-solution:

```
   User      System verstrichen 
  64.18        0.01       64.66
```

Again the "base R"-solution is faster:

```
   User      System verstrichen 
  10.89        0.00       10.99
```

The speed of the code is the formulation of the question is somewhere in between:

```
   User      System verstrichen 
  29.44        0.02       29.63
```

And here the result for the "rowslide"-solution:

```
   User      System verstrichen 
  14.38        0.00       14.48
```

Finally the "turn_out"-solution:

```
   User      System verstrichen 
  18.95        0.00       19.03
```

Answer (score 1):

I went a different route:

```
turn_out <- function(mat) {
  indx <- sweep(col(mat),1,1:nrow(mat)-1,"+")
  out <- matrix(NA, nrow(mat), ncol(mat)+nrow(mat)-1)
  for(i in 1:nrow(mat)) out[i,indx[i,]] <- mat[i,]
  out
}
```

**Test**

```
matrix.data <- matrix(1:15, 3)
turn_out(matrix.data)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    2    5    8   11   14   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    3    6    9   12   15
```